# How to handle error "#Error" when using CCur() in MS Access

Tags: sql, error-handling, ms-access-2010

I am trying to use Access to convert a table with a column of string into Currency if the string expression is valid.

My Input

```
line    data
--------------
8       Date
9       66.00
```

My query

```
SELECT line, CCur([data]) AS data
FROM Input;
```

My query output is

```
line    data
--------------
8       #Error
9       $66.00
```

My ideal output is

```
line    data
--------------
9       $66.00
```

I would like filter our the #Error in query. However, when I use the criteria field (i.e. >0), it prompts me Data type mismatch.

I also tried to use `IsError()` or `IsNumeric()` with IIF to catch the error. However, it still shows the #Error in the output.

I also found in post that `Nz()` could help. Still, the same #Error in my case.

Is there any function or tool to handle this error?

Answer (score 1):

Filter on `IsNumeric`:

```
SELECT line, CCur([data]) AS data
FROM Input
WHERE IsNumeric([data])
```

Note that this will still throw errors internally, it just doesn't return them. This can be a problem in certain situations (e.g. when using VBA to open a recordset). We can avoid that using IIF:

```
SELECT line, CCur(Iif(IsNumeric([data]), [data], 0)) AS data
FROM Input
WHERE IsNumeric([data])
```

Comment: Thanks. So, it is not possible to catch the error after the CCur? I can only filter out the NonNumeric input?

Comment: It's possible, just very much a bad practice, since depending on how the query is executed an error will actually halt execution, and generally you want queries to always work, not only when opened in Access itself.

Comment: Here's another gotcha to watch out for:  I had a SELECT line in a query that looked like `CCur(SUM(Col1 * Col2)) AS SumAmnt` (with the appropriate GROUP BY).  This query NEVER had to handle any nulls and never generated any.  However, when another query called this query for a join, it seemed to retroactively apply `CCur(SUM(null * null))` on non-matches and generate `#Error` instead of just setting `SumAmnt` to null.  I had to remove `CCur()` from the first query and apply it later in the second query.